# Embedding of a scheme into a regular scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Hello,

Is it true that if I have a scheme $X$ which is, say, Noetherian, of finite Krull dimension, and semi-separated (intersection of two open affines is again open affine), then I can find a locally closed embedding of it into a scheme of the same type, which is, in addition, regular?

I ask just of curiosity, or minor desire not to say "quasi-projective" when I want to have enough locally free objects.

Thank you,
Sasha

Comment: This isn't even true for specs of local rings if I recall correctly.  I'll try to find an example in a little bit.

Comment: Such schemes are divisorial (ie they have an ample family of line bundles) if they are quasi-separated and quasi-compact. I trust there must be many non-divisorial schemes, although I don't have an example at hand.

Comment: @Damian, this is interesting. As there are proper varieties with trivial Picard group, there are counterexamples with proper varieties. How to prove that a closed scheme in a regular scheme is divisorial ?


Comment: @Qing Liu. A regular is divisorial (see SGA6, II, Cor. 2.2.7.1) and  subscheme of a divisorial scheme is also divisorial (this follows from the definition).

Comment: @Qing Liu. Sorry: a regular *separated, noetherian* scheme is divisorial.

Comment: Hartshorne, Exercise III.5.9 gives an example as Roessler suggests.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A noetherian regular scheme is universally catenary (Matsumura, 14.B, 16.D), so any subscheme of a regular scheme is universally catenary.

But there are affine noetherian schemes (integral of dimension $2$) which are not universally catenary. See an example of Nagata in Matsumura, 14.E, or a slightly simpler one in EGA IV.5.6.11 (it consists in identifying two points of respective codimension 1 and 2 in an affine regular scheme of dimension 2).

Comment: As Emma says somewhere in Austen's novel, silly things do cease to be silly if they are done by sensible people in an impudent way. Identifying points of different codimension was surely not what she had in mind, but the observation surely applies!